# No me quiere insertar datos en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

no me quiere guardar ningun dato en la base de datos y en vista no me dice ningun error no se si tenga algun error en el codigo

Modelo

```
require_once('../admin/Conexion.php');
class Usuario{
    private $cedula, $usuario, $pSecreta, $respuesta, $TipoUsuario, $password, $password2;
    public function setCedula($cedula)
    {   $this->cedula = $cedula;
    }
    public function getCedula()
    {
    return $this->cedula;
    }
    public function setUsuario($usuario)
    {
$this->usuario = $usuario;
    }
    public function getUsuario()
    {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    public function setpSecreta($pSecreta)
    {
        $this->pSecreta = $pSecreta;

    }
    public function getpSecreta()
    {
        return $this->pSecreta;
    }
    public function setRespuesta($respuesta)
    {
        $this->respuesta = $respuesta;
    }

    public function getRespuesta()
    {
        return $this->respuesta;
    }
    public function setTipoUsuario($TipoUsuario){
      $this->TipoUsuario=$TipoUsuario;

    }

    public function getTipoUsuario(){

    return $this->TipoUsuario;
    }
     public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
public function GuardarUsuario(){
  $con=Conexion::getInstance();
  $sql="INSERT INTO $this->usuario(cedula, usuario, p_secreta, r_secreta,tipo-usuario, password) VALUES ('$this->cedula','$this->usuario', '$this->pSecreta', '$this->respuesta', '$this->TipoUsuario', '$this->password')";
 $result = $con->db->prepare($sql);
        $insert = $result->execute();
        return $insert;
  }

Controlador
require_once("../Modelo/Usuario.php");

$usuario= new Usuario("usuario");

  if(isset($_REQUEST['registrar'])){
      $usuario->setUsuario($_POST['usuario']);
      $usuario->setCedula($_POST['cedula']);
      $usuario->setpSecreta($_POST['p_secreta']);
      $usuario->setRespuesta($_POST['respuesta']);
      $usuario->setTipoUsuario($_POST['Tipo']);
      $usuario->setPassword($_POST['password']);

      $res=$usuario->GuardarUsuario();
 }
```

SQL

```
 CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `cedula` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `p_secreta` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `r_secreta` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo-usuario` text,
  `password` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Bueno, hay muchas cosas a mejorar en lo que estás implementando, desde el código hasta la tabla `usuario`. No estás controlando las variables del POST, no estás aplicando bien el criterio de consultas preparadas, cuando se hace un `INSERT` directo, los valores de columnas numéricas deberían ir sin comillas simples, aunque aquí no conviene hacer un `INSERT` directo... en la tabla, no entiendo por qué usas un campo de tipo `text` para `tipo-usuario`, ¿acaso piensas escribir un libro que describa el tipo de usuario?. En fin, muchas cosas a corregir. Pero debes decir si usas PDO o mysqli.

Comment: Si, soy nuevo en esto y quiero aprender un poco rapido a hacer por lo menos funcional esto porque tengo dias para presentar eso, bueno uso PDO, y que tipo de datos debo colocarle a usuario, tinytext no ?

Comment: No lo sé, depende de qué cantidad máxima de tipos de usuario va a haber, si son pocos puedes usar incluso `TINYINT` u otro de los `INT`, [aquí tienes las capacidades](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html). Ahora reviso tu código y te escribo una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudarias un monto ya que no tengo a quien recurrir ahora y solo habra 2 tipos de usuario y uno de eso es el administrador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javier esta es mi propuesta. He comentado casi todo en el código. De todos modos si tienes dudas me lo puedes decir en comentarios.

Primero empecemos por el controlador. Yo haría estos cambios:

### Controlador

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['registrar'])){
    /*
        1.-
        Primero recogemos los valores del POST usando ternarios, 
        asignando el valor o NULL en caso de que no traigan datos
        eso nos permitirá parar la inserción si alguno de los campos
        con la restricción NOT NULL viene vacío
    */
    $postUsuario     =(!empty($_POST['usuario']))   ?  $_POST['usuario']   :  NULL ;
    $postCedula      =(!empty($_POST['cedula']))    ?  $_POST['cedula']    :  NULL ;
    $postPSecreta    =(!empty($_POST['p_secreta'])) ?  $_POST['p_secreta'] :  NULL ;
    $postRespuesta   =(!empty($_POST['respuesta'])) ?  $_POST['respuesta'] :  NULL ;
    $postTipoUsuario =(!empty($_POST['Tipo']))      ?  $_POST['Tipo']      :  NULL ;
    $postPassword    =(!empty($_POST['password']))  ?  $_POST['password']  :  NULL ;

    /*
        2.-
        Aquí vamos a hacer lo que dijimos en (1)
    */
    if ($postCedula && $postUsuario && $postPSecreta && $postRespuesta && $postPassword) {
        /*
            3.-
            Trasladamos el require aquí, no tiene sentido ponerlo antes sin saber si lo vamos a usar
        */
        require_once("../Modelo/Usuario.php");
        $usuario= new Usuario("usuario");

        /*
            Asignamos las propiedades usando las variables creadas en 1.
        */
        $usuario->setUsuario($postUsuario);
        $usuario->setCedula($postCedula);
        $usuario->setpSecreta($postPSecreta);
        $usuario->setRespuesta($postRespuesta);
        $usuario->setTipoUsuario($postTipoUsuario);
        $usuario->setPassword($postPassword);

        $res=$usuario->GuardarUsuario();

    }else{
        $res="Uno de los campos requeridos es nulo, no se puede insertar";
    }
}else{
    $res="No se postearon datos";    
}
echo $res;  //puedes usar $res de otra forma o pasarlo a la vista para que lo imprima
```

---

### Modelo

Ahora veamos el método de inserción en la clase `Usuarios`. Yo he implementado un estilo de programación legible, que permita ver si tienes una columna de más o de menos, un marcador de más o de menos, un valor en el array de más o de menos. Además permite controlar el código en una sola vista, sin tener que desplazarte a la derecha de la pantalla cuando las instrucciones son demasiado largas.

Toda la clase quedaría igual, sólo modificas el método `GuardarUsuario()` como sigue:

```
    public function GuardarUsuario(){
        $con=Conexion::getInstance();
        /*
            1.-
            Controlamos la conexión
        */
        if ($con){
            /*
                2.
                Escribimos una consulta preparada real, con marcadores de posición ?
            */
            $sql="INSERT INTO `usuario` 
                    (
                        cedula, 
                        usuario, 
                        p_secreta, 
                        r_secreta,
                        tipo-usuario, 
                        password
                    ) 
                    VALUES 
                    (
                        ?,
                        ?,
                        ?,
                        ?,
                        ?,
                        ?
                    )";
            /*
                3. 
                Preparamos la consulta y evaluamos al mismo tiempo el estado de la preparación
            */
            if ($stmt = $con->db->prepare($sql)){

                /*
                    4.
                    Creamos un array con los valores que pasaremos aparte
                    aquí cada valor corresponde a cada marcador ? escrito en (2)
                    y deben ir en el orden en que están las columnas a la izquierda
                    del INSERT INTO
                */
                $arrParams=array(
                                    $this->cedula,
                                    $this->usuario,
                                    $this->pSecreta,
                                    $this->respuesta,
                                    $this->TipoUsuario,
                                    $this->password         
                                );
                /*
                    5.
                    A través del execute pasamos al array antes creado, 
                    neutralizando así el riesgo de inyección de código
                */
                $stmt->execute($arrParams);

                /*
                    6.
                    Contamos cuantas filas se insertaron, no necesariamente debe ocurrir la inserción
                    pueden haber errores como clave duplicada u otros, 
                    aquí se puede hacer un control suplementario si se quiere, verificando $totalInsert > 0
                */
                $totalInsert=$stmt->rowCount();
                $strInfo=($totalInsert > 0) ? "Se insertaron $totalInsert filas" : "No se pudo insertar. Error: ".$con->errorInfo()[2];

            } else {
                $strInfo="Error preparando la consulta: ".$con->errorInfo()[2];
            }
        }else{
            $strInfo="No hay conexión";
        }
        /*
            7.
            Devolvemos el valor de $strInfo que nos informará de lo ocurrido a lo largo de la ejecución
        */
        return $strInfo;
  }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Wao sin palabras, muchisimas gracias !!!, te comento que en el otro codigo coloque sencillamente un if(!empty(usuario))despues a ver llamado al metodo guardar usuarios para que se trasladara a index y un elsse con un alert para comprobar y solo me mandaba el alert :| y no se porque me pasa eso

Comment: @JavierValles me alegra de que te haya servido. En cuanto a lo que comentas sobre *el otro código*, no entendí a qué te refieres...

Comment: Al igual que el otro codigo no me lo guarda y dice que se insertaron 0 filas

Comment: Puede que la inserción viole alguna restricción. Yo he modificado el control de  la inserción de este modo: `$strInfo=($totalInsert > 0) ? "Se insertaron $totalInsert filas" : "No se pudo insertar. Error: ".$con->errorInfo()[2];`. Ponlo así y te dirá el motivo por el que no se está insertando. De paso te comento que conviene antes de hacer la inserción verificar si el registro no existe.

Comment: Me sale esto Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Conexion::errorInfo() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto2(BETA)\Modelo\Usuario.php:122 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto2(BETA)\Controlador\registrarusuario.php(21): Usuario->GuardarUsuario() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto2(BETA)\Modelo\Usuario.php on line 122

Comment: Quedamos en que usabas PDO, ¿cierto?, es extraño que no lo reconozca. De todos modos prueba así: `$strInfo=($totalInsert > 0) ? "Se insertaron $totalInsert filas" : "No se pudo insertar. Error: ".$stmt->errorInfo()[2];` o sea, cambia `$stmt`  por  `$con`.

Comment: Me dice lo mismo                       class Conexion
{
 public $db;      
    private static $dns = "mysql:dbname=sisgran;host=localhost"; 
    private static $user = "root";  
    private static $pass = "";    
    private static $instance; 
    public function __construct ()  
    {        
       $this->db = new PDO(self::$dns,self::$user,self::$pass); 
   } 
    public static function getInstance() 
    { 
     if(!isset(self::$instance)) 
      { 
       $object= __CLASS__; 
       self::$instance=new $object; 
      } 
      return self::$instance; 
     }    
    }

Comment: class Conexion 
 { public $db;
    private static $dns = "mysql:dbname=sisgran;host=localhost;"
    private static $user = "root";  
    private static $pass = ""; 
    private static $instance; 

    public function __construct ()  
    {        
       $this->db = new PDO(self::$dns,self::$user,self::$pass); 
   } 

    public static function getInstance() 
    { 
     if(!isset(self::$instance)) 
      { 
       $object= __CLASS__; 
       self::$instance=new $object; 
      } 
      return self::$instance; 
     }    
    }

Comment: No sé, me parece un poco raro tu código en la clase `Conexion`. Por ejemplo declaras `$instance`  como `private` si es la variable a la que piensas asignar la conexión no podrás usarla desde fuera de la clase. Y luego esto: `$object= __CLASS; self::$instance=new $object; ` no sé exactamente lo que significa. Prueba a devolver una nueva instancia llana de PDO, sin tantos rollos y cuando resuelvas eso entonces te creas una buena clase de conexión. Me parece que esa clase no te está devolviendo una instancia válida de PDO realmente. ¿Podrías indicar lo que imprime un `var_dump($con);`?

Comment: Hola, tal vez no me recuerdes, ya resolvi el problema de guardar los datos, creo que fue por la bd y los nombre que asigne no correspondía con lo que yo en el modelo colocaba, lo de PDO no tengo mucha idea, el codigo no es mio asi que no te puedo explicar bien como funciona(soy nuevo en esto), muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!